# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting Color Scale for Text, Not the Background

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Why is that the conditional formatting with color scale from Google Sheets only offers background coloring and not text coloring as well, like the single color does?

I have a column of player ratings which I would like to color scale so who's best/better is more easily recognizable — the whole sheet is ordered alphabetically, that's easier to manage overall. However, I think background color scaling is just too much, I would rather have only the text colored.

Is there an extension with this type of functionality?

[image: table]

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest you to request this feature by clicking `Help > Help Sheets improve` on the Sheets editor.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets is one way to tackle this, but it's not necessarily simple.

Alternatively, you could use multiple single color conditional formatting rules with a limited color palette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as of today (17 January 2020) - there is no such functionality internally supported in Google Sheets. as mentioned, you can make an inquiry and request such an option, but there is no guarantee you will get some any soon or any ever.